# ElasticSearch Highlighting Inner Field

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

I can't seem to get highlighting with ElasticSearch 0.90 to work on inner fields.
For instance, here's my document:

```
{ "foo": {  
    "bar": "test bonsai"  
}}
```

Queried as the following:

```
{ "query": {  
    "query_string": {  
      "query": "bonsai"
    }
  },  
  "highlight": { 
     "pre_tags": ["<b>"],
     "post_tags": ["</b>"], 
     "fields": { 
       "foo.bar": {}
     }  
  }  
}
```

It returns the query result, but without the highlighting information. If I don't nest my field (e.g. {"foo": "test bonsai"}, and request highlighting for "foo" field instead of "foo.bar") then it all works fine. But I can't get it work with nested fields.

I have tried different possible settings for fields, including "foo", "bar", "_all", "foo.*", and "*". I have also tried playing around with the mapping, including defining the "term_vector" (with_positions_offsets), "index", "analyzer", "stored" and "include_in_all". None does the trick.
On the documentation it seems to be supported ([here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/highlighting/), have a look at "bio.title" for example). But it doesn't work even when I use the exact same query.

Comment: It should work. Can u please post your mapping detail ? To get mapping : do a GET to http://localhost:9200/yourindex/yourtype/_mapping. To be able to highlight elasticsearch need the data from field own store or from _source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding "store": "yes" in the mapping solves the issue. (I mistakenly typed "stored" instead of "store" in the mapping)

Comment: Have you disabled the _source field?